# loading large geojson files on demand

Tags: geojson, viewport, mapbox-gl

we are implementing Mapbox gljs and we have several large geojson files roughly 70-100mb that we are loading from an API (REST URL) THe map does load the layer and will render it performantly which is fine however the browser memory increases significantly and clearly will not work on mobile view downloading such large files over the mobile network.

Is there a way to load a different URL based on the current viewport and change the data source on map movement for example?

Interested to know the best way to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for are [Vector Tiles](https://docs.mapbox.com/data/tilesets/guides/vector-tiles-introduction/). It's an implementation of spatial data, where whenever the viewport changes the Coordinates and Zoomlevel are send to a server and only the data within the bbox is served.

You need to create a [Tileset](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/tileset/#vector-tilesets) and either host it on a mapbox server or on your own tileserver. A tool worth recommanding for creating tilesets is is [tippecanoe](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe).